# Differentiate an append structure and a normal structure programmatically

Tags: abap, sap-r3

I'm running SAP R/3.

The table E071 stores objects from transport requests. There is a 4 character field in it called `OBJECT` that stores the object type. Like `PROG` for program, `TABD` for table, etc.

I have an internal table with objects selected from E071.

The objects with type `TABL` can both be a normal structure and an append structure.

In SE11, when you view a structure object, if it's a normal structure, it shows a text that says `Structure` by the object name. And if it's an append structure, it shows `Append Structure` there.

So there is a way to differentiate them.

How should I go about differentiating them inside my program? Is there any technical detail that is different between these two?

Comment: Can you update your question with some more detail information?

Comment: @UmarAbdullah Of course. What kind of detail should I add?

Comment: I suggest you take a moment to read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. It explains how to ask a good question that will get you better help with your problem.

Comment: @Mateus     https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @joanis I've read it, but I am unsure what other information I could add to make it more clear. Should I add a code example, or the table fields or something else?

Comment: Your question is very generic. It's not clear in what environment you're running, or what data you are seeing. We don't know what you tried and what it did. Were you able to partially solve your problem? If you show some work and how it didn't exactly solve your problem, someone could point you to what's missing. Yes, some code and some data would really help.

Comment: @joanis I've added a few more details; but I'm not at work and don't have any actual data to add. But I don't think it's that necessary to understand the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ABAP DDIC structures are stored in the `DD02L` table, which stores also miscellaneous objects like tables and views, which have these important columns :

- TABNAME : the object name
- TABCLASS : the object class **`INTTAB` for normal structure, `APPEND` for append structures**, and other values for tables and views (including `TRANSP` for transparent tables)
- SQLTAB : if the object is an append structure, it contains the object which it appends.

Comment: Thank you! I'll try using this table tomorrow at work. But it seems like it should solve my issues.